# Per MUC channel bot managed by ejabberd

Tags: service, process, bots, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I would like to run one service process per MUC channel on an ejabberd server. Ideally I would like ejabberd to start / monitor that process.

That is, when a new MUC gets opened ejabberd should start the bot process and tell it the channel name through commandline options. The process will then connect to that MUC on its own and do its thing. in case it crashes, ejabberd should notice and try to restart it. In case the MUC gets closed, so should the bot process. Is such functionality available with ejabberd?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything like that implemented.